# Using relative path

Tags: javascript

I had a url (say, https://www.abc.com/html5/) from which I fetch localization files, like this:

```
var url = '/html5/i18n/resources-locale_' + localize.language + '.js';
```

Now I have changed the url to https://www.abc.com/html5_something/

How can I use relative path for fetching the localization files?

Comment: That depends on the location of your page. Where does it reside?

Comment: see this:http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/591352/Get-WebSite-Root-Relative-Path-by-JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question I guess you are fetching the scripts from the same domain of the page your scripts are running, so you can use the `host` and `pathname` properties of the `location`<sup>[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)</sup> object, like this:

```
var url = window.location.host + '/html5/i18n/resources-locale_' + localize.language + '.js';
```

OR

```
var url = window.location.host + window.location.pathname + '/i18n/resources-locale_' + localize.language + '.js';
```